# how to change the method(md5/trust) in pg_hba using programming code or psql or any?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL on Windows. For some machines(more than 50 customers) I have set the auth method as `md5` in PostgreSQL authentication options in the `pg_hba.conf`. Now i want to change it to `trust` via `vb.net` or via SQL [see this](http://s21.postimg.org/opzotjpw7/hba.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not at time of writing (9.4) provide any SQL-level feature or utility command line tool to modify `pg_hba.conf` programmatically.

The simplest way to do what you want, if all the `pg_hba.conf` files across all the machines are identical, is to take a copy of the modified file and replace the old copy on all machines with your modified file. That can be done with whatever remote automation and management tools you use, or a simple script that does a `copy new_hba.conf %PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_hba.conf`. The same script could reload PostgreSQL's config via `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` or `pg_ctl reload`.

If the files aren't all identical and you have to preserve any existing local modifications made to each file, it's a little trickier.

You need to open the file as a text file, read each line, and split it into fields by whitespace (runs of tabs/spaces).

For every line, write the original line back to the file unless it's the line you want to modify. For that line, write a replacement instead. If you don't find the line you want to replace while processing the file, add a new line at the end before closing the file.

On unix operating systems there are existing useful utilities for this, like `sed`, `awk` and `perl`.

On Windows, you can write your own equivalent with some fairly simple VB.net as this is a simple-ish task in basically any programming language that supports file I/O. That's probably going to be your best bet. Search for examples of how to modify text based config files using VB.net for examples.